# Change view height (and make it scrollable) after AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-linearlayout

I have a fragment tab implementation with the tabContent with `FrameLayout` as follow:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/tab_content_wrapper">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:background="#434343"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Then within the realcontent, I could add `ListView` and it's scrollable. However, the trouble happens when I want to have a `RelativeLayout` to have a fixed height content and add the `ListView` below it. It has the following resource layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/some_content_with_listview"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/pre_list_view_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

After `AsyncTask`, my_list_view is populated with items and it's showing within very short scrollable `ListView`. I can't seem to be able to make the `LinearLayout` taller to contain the entire `ListView` without scroll. So to clarify, I want to make the **`ListView` NOT scrollable** but to make the **`LinearLayout` scrollable** within the realtabcontent (FrameLayout)

Thanks Ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a different layout for your relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/pre_list_view_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And add it as header to the list view.

```
 //inflate this layout and get view object
lvMyListView.addHeaderView(view,null,false);
```

You can check this like out for more info on adding header

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter

Comment: It works.  Didn't think about header could be a full complex layout on its own right.  For some reason, always think of header as a simple layout.  Thanks.